# How do I retrieve a part of the html tag in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the code i used to extract this tag from the webpage:

```
director = movies[0].find_all("a")
```

I want to extract the director Frank Databont from the HMTL tag below using BeautifulSoup.

```
[<a href="/title/tt0111161/" title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman">The Shawshank Redemption</a>]
```

Do I need to convert this to a string and use RegEx to find the director or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id maybe try:

```
director = movies[0].find("a")[title]
```

I have done something similar for getting the hyperlinks from  tags by using:

`soup.find("a", href=true)[href]`

So the syntax could work similarly for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I made it work like this, thank you!
director = movies[0].find("a")["title"].split(",")[0].replace("(dir.)", "").strip()

Answer (score 1):

You can `split()` the title text by "," and check if `(dir.)`:

```
[d for x in soup.find_all("a") for d in x['title'].split(',') if '(dir.)' in d ]
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="/title/tt0111161/" title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman">The Shawshank Redemption</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

director = [d for x in soup.find_all("a") for d in x['title'].split(',') if '(dir.)' in d ]
```